# Pareto frontier indices using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to label a number of numpy vectors (matrix *M*), so that the label displays the Pareto frontier index.

For instance, the non-dominated set of vectors (`v0`) would be labelled with Pareto frontier index `0`, the set of non-dominated vectors *v1* (*v1 = M - v0*) would be labelled with index `1`, the next set/frontier of non-dominated vectors *v2* (*v2 = M - v0 - v1*) `2` and so on until all vectors of matrix *M* are labelled.

I've put a few test cases together, but whatever I come up with it either extremely inefficient (don't care too much at the moment) or just doesn't work.

```
mat1 = np.asarray([
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
])

calc_fronts(mat1) == [0, 1, 1]

mat2 = np.asarray([
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 22, 3, 4, 5, 6],
])

calc_fronts(mat2) == [0, 1, 0]


mat3 = np.asarray([
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
    [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 4],
])

calc_fronts(mat3) == [0, 1, 2]


mat4 = np.asarray([
    [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7],
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [1, 22, 2, 4, 5, 6],
])

calc_fronts(mat4) == [0, 0, 0]
```

Vector *x* dominates *y* if foreach a in x, b in y: a >= b AND there exists at least one *a* in *x* for which *a > b*.

This is my attempt:

```
def calc_fronts_2(vecs):
    n = vecs.shape[0]
    # find the most dominating
    m = np.zeros(vecs.shape, dtype=bool)
    dominates = []
    for i, vec in enumerate(vecs):
        for x in xrange(n):
            m[x] = i != x
        mvecs = np.ma.masked_array(vecs, mask=~m)
        # print 'i=', i
        # print 'all better  \n', np.all(vec >= mvecs, axis=1)
        # print 'at least one\n', np.any(np.all(vec > vecs[m], axis=0))
        # print 'at least one\n', vec > mvecs
        # print 'at least one\n', np.any(vec > mvecs, axis=1)

        dom = np.where(np.all(vec >= mvecs, axis=1) & np.any(vec > mvecs, axis=1))
        dom = dom[0]
        dominates.append(dom.tolist())
    # print dominates

    dominated_by = [[j for j in xrange(n) if i in dominates[j]] for i in xrange(n)]

    print 'domin:\n', dominates
    print 'dom by\n', dominated_by
    ranks = np.empty(n, dtype=int)
    ranks.fill(-1)
    for r in xrange(n):
        remove = set()
        for i in xrange(n):
            if ranks[i] == -1 and len(dominated_by[i]) == 0:
                ranks[i] = r
                remove.add(i)
        for ranked in remove:
            for domby in dominated_by:
                if ranked in domby:
                    domby.remove(ranked)
        if np.all(ranks == -1):
            break
    return ranks
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you made a typo in the first example. In `mat1` the second row dominates the third row, right? So the first result should be `[0, 1, 2]` (?).

Comment: You're right. I also found a typo in the 2nd example. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my quite array-heavy attempt, to hopefully give some new ideas. Though be aware that a (m,m,n) temp array is created (when `M` is (m,n) shaped).

```
import numpy as np

def calc_fronts(M):
    i_dominates_j = np.all(M[:,None] >= M, axis=-1) & np.any(M[:,None] > M, axis=-1)
    remaining = np.arange(len(M))
    fronts = np.empty(len(M), int)
    frontier_index = 0
    while remaining.size > 0:
        dominated = np.any(i_dominates_j[remaining[:,None], remaining], axis=0)
        fronts[remaining[~dominated]] = frontier_index

        remaining = remaining[dominated]
        frontier_index += 1
    return fronts
```

Demo:

```
In [217]: M = np.array([[ 0, 18,  1],
     ...:               [ 4,  8, 11],
     ...:               [ 3, 19,  3],
     ...:               [18,  1, 19],
     ...:               [16,  7, 13],
     ...:               [ 3, 18,  3],
     ...:               [15, 13, 19],
     ...:               [13,  5, 13],
     ...:               [ 2, 16, 16],
     ...:               [ 9, 14, 17]])

In [218]: calc_fronts(M)
Out[218]: array([2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```